# Any Lightbox for Cross-Domain Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, lightbox

Searching alot on this topic but no solution... :(
Looking for any lightbox for pictures in Cross Domain Environment

Thankx in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here, but if you're looking to circumvent the cross-domain JS restrictions, you can always create a PHP page (or something similar) on your server that fetches images from another domain and serves them as local.

Here is some jQuery Code to change an image object's `src` attribute to show a specific picture. Lets say we want to show the image `http://www.someotherdomain.com/images/pictureofbacon.png`....

```
var urlStr = 'http://www.someotherdomain.com/images/pictureofbacon.png';

//encode the image's url for passing 
var url_enc = encodeURIComponent(urlStr); 

$('#imageBacon').attr(
    'src', 'http://www.yourdomain.com/getPhoto?url=' + url_enc
); //call your php page, passing to it the encode image url
```

Then, in your PHP page, you can get the URL and process the image locally. This PHP is tested to work (requires GD2), assuming you pass it a valid image URL.

**getPhoto.php**

```
<?php
    $url = $_REQUEST['url'];
    SendImageToBrowser ($url); 

    function SendImageToBrowser($file){
     $info = getimagesize($file);
  $final_width=$info[0];
  $final_height=$info[1];

     switch ( $info[2] ) {
       case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
         $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
        break;
       case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
         $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
        break;
       case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
         $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
        break;
       default:
         return false;
     }
     imagecopyresampled($image_resized, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $final_width, $final_height, $width_old, $height_old);
        $mime = image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]);
        header("Content-type: $mime");
        $output = NULL;

     switch ( $info[2] ) {
       case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
         imagegif($image, $output);
       break;
       case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
         imagejpeg($image, $output);
       break;
       case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
         imagepng($image, $output);
       break;
       default:
         return false;
     }
     return true;
 }
?>
```